# Form Input Checkbox Resets API Response Value When Unchecked?

Tags: javascript, api, express, input, checkbox

So I have this app that you select a checkbox & tip and it will show the total amount and add/subtract when you unselect/select other options.

Here is a codepen of the basic app not **including the API function**
https://codepen.io/jaysomo10/pen/mdXoRWz

So you can see from the codepen, the basic checkboxes and tips work completely fine.

I am connected to an API and after I add my delivery address, it will calculate the delivery fee and add it to my total value.

My problem is that once I calculate the delivery fee, then I select a checkbox option, and then I **unselect that option**, it will reset the total value and now my total value doesn't show the delivery fee included.

**Example:** I select `$10` menu option and then `$5` tip so my total is now `$15`. Then, I go and calculate my delivery fee and it will show `$7` delivery fee + the `$15` food total which equals `$22` for everything. The problem is if I unselect the `$10` food item, it will reset the order total from `$22` back to the tip value of `$5` but my delivery fee is still showing in the HTML as `$7` yet the order value total isn't including the delivery fee in the total.

Here is my JS function for the delivery fee. **Note this code works completely fine as long as I only select checkboxes and never unselect any. The moment I unselect a checkbox is when the values reset and the order total becomes wrong because it no longer includes the delivery fee.**

```
async function getFee() {
  const payload = getFormValues();
  const finalPayload = JSON.stringify(payload);

  const formInput = document.querySelector("form");
  console.log(formInput);

  if (formInput.checkValidity()) {
    console.log("YES");

    const response = await fetch("/get-fee", {
      method: "POST",
      body: finalPayload,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
      .then(async (response) => {
        const resp = await response.json();
        return resp;
      })
      .catch((rejected) => {
        console.log(rejected);
      });

    const deliveryField = document.getElementById("fee");
    const orderTotal = document.getElementById("total");
    tipVal = document.querySelector(".tips:checked").value;
    window.tips = tipVal;

    foodTotal.textContent = `$${(window.menuItems / 100).toFixed(2)}`;
    tipTotal.textContent = `$${(window.tips / 100).toFixed(2)}`;
    deliveryField.innerHTML = `$${(response.fee / 100).toFixed(2)}`;
    orderTotal.textContent = `$${(
      (Number(window.menuItems) + Number(window.tips) + response.fee) /
      100
    ).toFixed(2)}`;
  } else {
    console.log("You need to fill out the form");
  }

}
```

My issue is I don't know how to get the `response.fee` value into my other JS file that allows me to add/subtract the checkbox values and tips.

Basically, the JS file in my codepen doesn't know the delivery fee until after I submit an address, hence the logic for the code simply adds/subtracts the values and it can't include the delivery fee in the total because it doesn't know what it is until I submit that info